# Removing double quotes during rendering of text file

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportbuilder

Reporting Services when a value has a comma and when report data is exported (rendered) to text file it puts double quotes around those values ex: Mike Electric, and Pluming.
I need the data to show up with the comma in the names (bank formatting requires it) but no double quotes enclosing them ("Mike Electric, and Pluming"). I was trying to write custom code that would remove the double quotes sure as to why. Are there other ways to resolve this in SSRS Report Builder? have provided custom code, what is wrong with it?

```
Imports Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportRendering

Function RemoveQuotes(ByVal input As String) As String
    Dim renderFormat as RenderingFormat = Report.RenderFormat
    If (renderFormat.Name = "TEXT") AndAlso input.Contains(",") Then
        Return input.Replace("""", "") ' Remove existing quotes
    Else
        Return input
    End If
End Function
```

Thank you in advance

Tried custom code

```
Imports Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportRendering

Function RemoveQuotes(ByVal input As String) As String
    Dim renderFormat as RenderingFormat = Report.RenderFormat
    If (renderFormat.Name = "TEXT") AndAlso input.Contains(",") Then
        Return input.Replace("""", "") ' Remove existing quotes
    Else
        Return input
    End If
End Function
```

also tried replace statement, but it does not work since the double quotes are not in report only export text file.

ex:REPLACE(NAME.VALUE,"""","")

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the easiest way would be to add a new export format to SSRS, you could use a
to `Tab` delimiter for exmaple instead of a comma, that way the renderer will not have to do anything commas. You can use any other delimiter you like obviously, such as a pipe character `|` .

First you need to locate the RSReportServer.config file. On my server is was here

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MyServerName\Reporting Services\ReportServer`  but the location might vary depending on your setup.

---

**MAKE A BACKUP BEFORE YOU START JUST IN CASE THINGS GO WRONG!**

---

Open the file and locate the `<Render>...</Render>` block

At the end of the block add the following (this will add both a pipe and tab separated option)

```
    <Extension Name="TAB" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
    <OverrideNames>
        <Name>TAB Delimited</Name>
    </OverrideNames>
    <Configuration>
        <DeviceInfo>
            <FieldDelimiter>&#9;</FieldDelimiter>
            <UseFormattedValues>False</UseFormattedValues>
            <NoHeader>False</NoHeader>
            <FileExtension>txt</FileExtension>
            <Qualifier>'</Qualifier>
        </DeviceInfo>
    </Configuration>
    </Extension>

    <Extension Name="PIPE" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
    <OverrideNames>
        <Name>PIPE Delimited</Name>
    </OverrideNames>
    <Configuration>
        <DeviceInfo>
            <FieldDelimiter>|</FieldDelimiter>
            <UseFormattedValues>False</UseFormattedValues>
            <NoHeader>False</NoHeader>
            <FileExtension>txt</FileExtension>
            <Qualifier>'</Qualifier>
        </DeviceInfo>
    </Configuration>
    </Extension>
```

Restart SSRS and you should have your new export options.